# C++ "assuming" template type in a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, derived-class

I am trying to declare a generic variable and the compiler seems to be assuming the type according to the base class.

Here is a part of my code:

```
class CompGate:public Gate<bool>{
protected:
    virtual bool eval()const=0;
    Gate* _v1;
    Gate* _v2;
public:
    template<class T, class T2>
    void connectInputs(Gate<T>* v1, Gate<T2>* v2){
        _v1=v1;
        _v2=v2;
    }
};
```

I get `cannot convert 'Gate<double>*' to 'Gate<bool>*' in assignement` when I use `connectInputs` in my main function.

It seems like `Gate* _v1` is defined as `Gate<bool>* v1` for some reason.

Sorry for my English..

Comment: Did you expect the compiler to see `_v1=v1` and then deduce the type of `_v1` to be `Gate<T>`?

Comment: @nwp , yes I expected `_v1` to be of type `Gate*` where the template type is not specified.

Comment: Gate refers to the __current instantiation__ if it's used inside a class template. You are deriving from Gate<bool>, so Gate will refer to Gate<bool>.

Comment: @super ok so is there any way I can declare `_v` as `Gate<T>`?

Comment: Can you give some example to show how you intend to use this? Are _v1 and _v2 always the same kind of Gate for example? How dynamic you need to be during run-time will most likely affect the design choice.

Comment: You need to template your class. There is no type `Gate` without template attached.

If you had `CompGate<T>`, you could then have its member be of type `Gate<T>*`.

Comment: @super `v1` and `v2` are not always the same type. Here, Gates<T> are structures that take [0-n] parameters and return a value of type T. I want CompGate to take 2 parameters (ex: int and double) and compare them (check if v1 > v2).

Comment: For example IfGate takes a `bool` a `T` and a `T` and returns a `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses a makeGate template function to make the gate without having to specify what kind it should be. All the CompGates derive from the same baseclass so you later on don't need to know what types it's comparing to call it's eval function.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A>
class Gate {
    public:
    ~Gate() {}
    A data;
    A eval() { return data; }
};

class CompGateBase {
    public:
    virtual ~CompGateBase();
    virtual bool eval() = 0;
};

template<class T1, class T2>
class CompGate: public Gate<bool>{
public:
    bool eval() { return _v1->eval() > _v2->eval(); }
    void connectInputs (T1& v1, T2& v2) {
        _v1 = &v1;
        _v2 = &v2;
    }
protected:
    T1* _v1;
    T2* _v2;
};

template<class G1, class G2>
CompGate<G1, G2> makeGate(G1& gate1, G2& gate2) {
    CompGate<G1, G2> compGate;
    compGate.connectInputs(gate1, gate2);
    return compGate;
}

int main() {
    Gate<double> G1;
    G1.data = 8.8;
    Gate<int> G2;
    G2.data = 8;

    auto gate = makeGate(G1, G2);
    std::cout << gate.eval() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a better version but don't want to precise the data types every time I instantiate a `CompGate`.

To answer your question : Just because other gates may refer to `CompGate` as a `Gate<bool>`

Comment: Do you need to be able to change what kind of Gate a CompGate will refer to during runtime? Then you need polymorphic Gate's that derive from a base class. Depending on how you use the CompGates you might want to do the same with the CompGate class. You need to supply some example usage.

Comment: ok first of all I need to clarify that every `Gate` has its `eval` function which returns the value of the gate. Here is an example : I declare `DoubleGate d(3.14);` it's `eval()` returns 3.14 all the time. Then I declare `IntGate i(2);` then `CompGate c;` then connect them using `c.connectInputs(&d,&i)`. `c.eval()` coresponds to `d.eval()>i.eval()` which is `true`

Comment: Ok I'm kinda new to C++ and I intend to make a program where I can connect "gates" between each other to create images. Gates are like functions, they can "return" one type of data (int, double, bool..). There are different kinds of Gates. CompGate stands for Compare. it takes 2 variables, compare them and return a bool. Now I am having some trouble compiling this class : I am having difficulties handling data types using templates. Any gate is a derived class of Gate<returnType> so CompGate must be derived from Gate<bool> Here an example of how it should work https://imgur.com/sza8Cze

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your input a bit more.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you very much

Comment: I just found another way : `void*`

Comment: Using void* throws away all type safety, and is generally considered poor practice in modern c++ because you have tools to avoid it. You run the risk of making invisible bugs in your code that on the surface seem to work.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is why my class CompGate is now using only `double` variables. So now I have `Gate<double> _g1` and `Gate<double> _g2` which works perfectly.